# Swift 3 UIPicker

Tags: swift, ios, swift3, cocoa-touch

I have been making a little test app to try and learn Swift 3 / iOS better. I started a while ago with with Swift 2 but stopped, so getting back into it, but there is so much iOS to learn!

It seems to work fine, and I made it so that it worked by inserting the pickerview value into the textfield when a user presses the "done" button. I found that without doing that if a user wants the first value of the pickerview it doesn't get inserted like it does when you scroll to another value. I left in the relative code for my controller.

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
 let pickerData: [String] = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
 var picker = UIPickerView()

 @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

 // set the pickerview for number of periods
func setPickerView(){
    picker.dataSource = self
    picker.delegate = self
    textField.inputView = picker
    textField.inputAccessoryView = initToolBar()
}

// build the toolbar for uipicker, so a user can select a value
func initToolBar() -> UIToolbar {
    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
    toolBar.isTranslucent = true
    toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red:14.0/255, green:122.0/255, blue:254.0/255, alpha: 1)
    toolBar.sizeToFit()
    // TODO need to update actions for all buttons
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: nil)
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(pickerDoneAction))
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    return toolBar
}

// Take pickerview value and insert into textfield, this stops the first row on load not being loaded into textfield
func pickerDoneAction(sender: UITextField){
    let indexPath = picker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
    textField.text = pickerData[indexPath]
    // resign first responder dropping the uipicker
    UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(resignFirstResponder), to:nil, from:nil, for:nil)
}

// Pickerview delegates
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int { return 1 }
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {return pickerData.count}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {return pickerData[row]}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    textField.text = pickerData[row]
}
 }
```

I'd like to take this if the code is pretty decent and make it work for multiple `uipickers` with different data sources on the same screen. Although I'm not too sure of how yet

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix would be adding an empty extra value at the beginning of the data source

> ```
> let pickerData: [String] = ["","1", "2", "3", "4"]
> ```

or you could `let textField.text = pickerData[0]` as soon as they start editing the textField